# How to query on a Mongodb document and on a reference object at a time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I’m trying to create a filter to manage orders (seller)

orders are composed of "**price**", "**country**", "**product type**",
and **seller** and **customer** informations

```
order: {
 _id:""
 price: $750
 country:"Italy"
 customer: objectID
 Seller: objectID
 productType: "smartphone"

}
 
 
customer: {
  _id:""
  location:"Italy",
  paymentType:"paypal"
  languages:"it"

}

Seller: {
  _id:"278"
  location:"UK"
  languages:"en"

}
```

let’s say the **seller**( _id: 278)  wants to find all his orders:

```
  order with a minimum price of $500 and a maximum price of $800
  and order in the country "italy" or "belgium"
  and order with customers who have paid with "paypal" or "stripe"
  and order with customer who speaks English or Italian
```

So I made this request:

```
  Order.find({ $and:[
    seller: 278,
    price: {$gte: 500, $lte: 800},
    country: { $or:["Italy","belgium"] },
    customer: { paymentType: { $or:["paypal","stripe"] },
               languages:{ $or:["en","it"] }
]})
```

and of course I have an error :

```
 " Cast to ObjectId failed for value " paymentType: { $or:["paypal","stripe"]
at path "customer " for model Order"
```

I don’t know what to put because I’m not targeting any particular customer I don’t need to target client id I don’t understand

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator. You don't need `$and`:

```
Order.find({ 
    seller: 278,
    price: {$gte: 500, $lte: 800},
    country: { $in: ["Italy","belgium"] },
    "customer.paymentType": { $in: ["paypal","stripe"] },
    languages:{ $in: ["en","it"] }
})
```

Comment: this works even if there is a reference object?

Comment: Please provide proper and valid input data, then you will get better answers.